# Mongoose distinct query with regex and a limit?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm running the following code which returns many results.  I want to limit the results to the first 10 docs.  How can I add a "limit" to the following mongoose query?

```
var reg = new RegExp('^'+id,'i');

models.examples.distinct('myId', {myId: reg}, function(err, docs) {
  console.log("docs: " + util.inspect(docs));
  res.send(docs);
});
```

Comment: Found a workaround: docs = docs.slice(0,9);  Might not be the best option though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you cant call limit on distinct - please vote for: [SERVER-2130](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2130).
You could utilise the [aggregation framework](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#aggregate) to limit the number returned over the wire, by doing a `$group` and then a `$limit`.

Comment: Thanks Ross. I voted for the enhancement on the mongo jira site.